# Implementing Google Play Game Services - How to let user sign in

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-games, google-api-client

It's my first time working with a google API as I'm fairly new to android programming. I've been trying to implement google play game services and display leaderboards in my app (it's a game as you may have guessed), and have had some difficulty following along with google's documentation.

I have set a button and would like to let the user sign in when it is tapped, and leave the user logged on until they log out afterwards. I have programmed this following the documentation:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

  Button bLeaderboard;

  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

  private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
  private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
  private boolean mSignInClicked = false;


@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bLeaderboard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLeaderboard);
    bLeaderboard.setOnClickListener(this);

     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bLeaderboard:

            mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

}
```

The problem is that whenever I tap on the leaderboard button the app crashes and I get this error message:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.game, PID: 26284
>                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zzasf(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I have also been unable to understand what to do with these three implemented methods:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have not been able to find any tutorials on this except for google's documentation, which as I said earlier, I struggle to comprehend and follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me correctly

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

// Client used to interact with Google APIs
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInflow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;
GameHelper gameHelper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    gameHelper.setup(new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Signed in Succeed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });



    setContentView(view);

    //for load all Score card



    scorecard=(Button)findViewById(R.id.score_card);
    scorecard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(mGoogleApiClient), 1);

        }
    });





}
private boolean isScoreResultValid(final Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult scoreResult) {
    return scoreResult != null && GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK == scoreResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() && scoreResult.getScore() != null;
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // The player is signed in. Hide the sign-in button and allow the
    // player to proceed.
    // now submit your high_score
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_easy),high_score);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // already resolving
        return;
    }

    // if the sign-in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
    // launch the sign-in flow
    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInflow) {
        mAutoStartSignInflow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
        // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
        // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
        // an issue with sign-in, please try again later."
        /*if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, "Sign in error")) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }*/
    }

    // Put code here to display the sign-in button
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Attempt to reconnect
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
            // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
            // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
            // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                    requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_failure);
        }
    }
}
// Call when the sign-in button is clicked
private void signInClicked() {
    mSignInClicked = true;
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

// Call when the sign-out button is clicked
private void signOutclicked() {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
}

 }
```

Comment: Remember also declare the email-id of the tester in google play game service console..